# Java platform management in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am developing a JavaFx application and everything was working well but for some days now, I am not able to execute my application, it seems that the configuration of my project is messed up.

I am saying this because when I try to launch the application I have this message :

```
Executing fittslaw.FittsLaw from C:\Users\Julien\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FittsLaw\dist\run1331123992\FittsLaw.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15/bin/java
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._submitForLaterInvocation(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._submitForLaterInvocation(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.submitForLaterInvocation(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

You can clearly see that the platform path is wrong with the part `/bin/java`.

I found on the web some method to manage the platform, but it was exactly what I did before.

In properties of my project, I go in Libraries and click on Manage Plateform then I select the platform and go in JavaFx tab and I select my jdk using the button Browse.

But the path that I can configure is limited to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15` , so the bad part with slashes instead of backslashes is not an error of my own and i don't know how to change this.

If someone have any clues.

Comment: Till now Windows also accepts slashes`/` instead of the official backslashes `\` (POSIX compatibility). I guess it has more to do with oracle getting rid of com.sun classes. A JDK update?

Comment: It seems that creating a platform with the last update 45 fix the problem, thank you